# shopt: what is wrong with "&&"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I dont get why when I do them separately it works but with `&&` it doesnt (it's not a [`(` problem like here](https://superuser.com/questions/1280432/im-getting-a-bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token))... what am I missing?

```
11:20:06 $ shopt -s extglob && shopt -s globstar && for f in **/*.@(jpg|jpeg|png|gif); do [[ -f "$f.webp" ]] || cwebp -quiet -q 80 "$f" -o "$f.webp"; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
11:20:11 $ shopt -s extglob && shopt -s globstar 
11:20:16 $ for f in **/*.@(jpg|jpeg|png|gif); do [[ -f "$f.webp" ]] || cwebp -quiet -q 80 "$f" -o "$f.webp"; doneError! Could not process file img/colorpicker/colormap.gif
11:20:23 $
```

Comment: `shopt -s extglob globstar` the `;` represents a new line, which is needed, don't put them on the same line. without the `;` separating them...

Comment: I need to do this in one line (it's a one-liner cronjob)

Comment: Yes, so did you try using a `;` to separate the shopt from the other commands?

Comment: You mean instead of the "`&&`" just once (= the last one)?

Comment: For cron, you can force a newline in the command itself: `shopt -s extglob globstar%for f in ...`. That should be sufficient for the shell executing the command to force `shopt` to execute before parsing the rest of its input. That's one line in crontab, but two separate lines of input passed to the shell.

Comment: I might be better for the future reader to forget about one-liners, and just put that in a small script, called from the crontab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the first version is all on one line, the shell has to parse the whole thing before executing any of it. But `**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)` is only valid syntax *after `shopt -s extglob` has been executed*... which is after the line is through the parsing phase.

If this has to be a one-liner, I don't know a great way around it. But you should be able to cheat using a brace expansion instead of an extended glob, and modifying the test-for-files:

```
shopt -s globstar && for f in **/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}; do [[ -f "$f" && ! -f "$f.webp" ]] && cwebp -quiet -q 80 "$f" -o "$f.webp"; done
```

Note that since `globstar` takes effect when the wildcard is expanded, not during the initial parsing pass, this problem doesn't apply to it.

Explanation: bash does brace expansion before expanding wildcards, so

```
for f in **/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif};
```

expands to

```
for f in **/*.jpg **/*.jpeg **/*.png **/*.gif;
```

...and then each of those wildcard patterns gets expanded separately. There's a potential problem with this: if there isn't at least one file matching each of the four patterns, the unmatched pattern(s) will be left alone as sort of bogus placeholders.

For example, if there are only .jpg and .png files, the fully expanded list might include something like this:

```
path/to/image1.jpg
path/to/image2.jpg
**/*.jpeg
path/to/image3.png
**/*.gif
```

...and it'll go ahead and run the loop with each of those, including `**/*.jpeg` and `**/*.gif`. That's why I had to modify the test inside the loop to

```
[[ -f "$f" && ! -f "$f.webp" ]] && cwebp ...
```

The `-f "$f"` test will fail on the unexpanded wildcards, and prevent it from trying to make webp versions of nonexistent files. You could equivalently use this, which is closer to the original test:

```
[[ ! -f "$f" || -f "$f.webp" ]] || cwebp ...
```

But I though it was more intuitive in the other form.

BTW, another possible fix for the unmatched wildcard problem is to add `shopt -s nullglob`, which makes the unmatched ones vanish.